# How can I construct this string in a nicer fasion?

Tags: c#, winforms, string

I have a tool with a configurable delay (Timespan), and I want to set the text of a label depending on the value.  Here is my code as it stands:

```
    StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();
    if (Settings.Default.WaitPeriod.Hours > 0)
    {
        time.AppendFormat("{0} hour(s)", Settings.Default.WaitPeriod.Hours);
    }

    if (Settings.Default.WaitPeriod.Minutes > 0)
    {
        time.AppendFormat("{0}{1} minute(s)", time.Length > 0 ? " and " : "", Settings.Default.WaitPeriod.Minutes);
    }

    if (Settings.Default.WaitPeriod.Seconds > 0)
    {
        time.AppendFormat("{0}{1} second(s)", time.Length > 0 ? " and " : "", Settings.Default.WaitPeriod.Seconds);
    }

    this.questionLabel.Text = String.Format("What have you been doing for the past {0}?", time);
```

I find the "(s)" particulary irritating - but don't  want a million if/ternary if statements.

So, **ignoring the non-localized strings, can you think of a nicer way to do this?**

Comment: not a real answer, but it seems like it's a bit of an awkward phrasing of the question. Are you sure you don't just want to approximate? I think it would be acceptable to ask someone "What have you been doing for the past 3 hours?" instead of "What have you been doing for the past 3 hours and 5 minutes and 23 seconds?" And if you do keep the existing detailed question, you probably want to say "X hours, Y minutes, and Z seconds" instead of "X hours and Y minutes and Z seconds".

Comment: @csharptest.net - no, must be smaller units.
@Brian - very good point.  It would be even nicer to convert 01:15:00 to "hour and a quater" but I think it would add to the complexity.

Comment: I have modified the question.

Comment: You need to specify the problem a little more. Would a timespan of 1 minute be "0 0/4" or "0 1/4", in units of 15 minutes?

Comment: Good point!  I'll update my question.

Comment: I rolled back to the original question.  scwagners solution will give me what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private void AddValue(StringBuilder time, int units, string unitLabel)
{
    if (units > 0)
    {
        if (0 < time.Length)
        {
            time.Append(" and ");
        }
        time.AppendFormat("{0} {1}{2}", units, unitLabel, (1 == units ? String.Empty : "s"));
    }
}

private void YourExistingMethod()
{
    StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();
    AddValue(time, Settings.Default.WaitPeriod.Hours, "hour");
    AddValue(time, Settings.Default.WaitPeriod.Minutes, "minute");
    AddValue(time, Settings.Default.WaitPeriod.Seconds, "second");
    this.questionLabel.Text = String.Format("What have you been doing for the past {0}?", time);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, old holdouts from my C days of putting numbers on the left side of comparisons to prevent accidental assignments.

Comment: @llamaoo7 Yes, that's because when I did the first "if" I wrote in the "acceptable" format being conscious of it, and then went back into my "normal" style later.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that addresses Brian Schroth's comment.
Sample outputs:

```
2 hours and 1 second
1 hour, 4 minutes, and 50 seconds
1 minute
```

The code:

```
public static string FriendlyTime(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {    
    List<string> terms = new List<string>();
    AddValue(terms, hours, "hour", "hours");
    AddValue(terms, minutes, "minute", "minutes");
    AddValue(terms, seconds, "second", "seconds");      
    return FriendlyJoin(terms);
}

public static void AddValue(List<string> list, int count, string single, string plural) {
    if (count != 0) {
        list.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", count, count == 1 ? single : plural));
    }
}

public static string FriendlyJoin(List<string> list) {
    if (list.Count == 0) {
        return "";
    } else if (list.Count == 1) {
        return list[0];
    } else if (list.Count == 2) {
        return String.Format("{0} and {1}", list[0], list[1]);
    } else {        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();     
        for (int i=0; i<list.Count-1; i++) {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}, ", list[i]);
        }
        sb.AppendFormat("and {0}", list[list.Count-1]);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this seems more complex than my original code!

Answer (score 0):

```
        StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();
        TimeSpan useme = Settings.Default.WaitPeriod;
        int[] j = new int[] { useme.Hours, useme.Minutes, useme.Seconds };
        string[] single = new string[] { "hour", "minute", "second" };
        string[] multiple = new string[] { "hours", "minutes", "seconds" };

        for (int i = 0; i < j.Length; i++)
        {
            if (j[i] > 0) time.AppendFormat("{0}{1} {2}", time.Length > 0 ? " and " : "", j[i], j[i] > 1 ? multiple[i] : single[i]);
        }

        string output = String.Format("What have you been doing for the past {0} {1}?", time);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't care about readability I'd do something like the following for efficiency's sake:

```
        time = new StringBuilder();
        if (duration.Hours > 0) 
            time.Append(duration.Hours).Append(" hour").Append(duration.Hours > 1 ? "s" : String.Empty)
                .Append(duration.Minutes > 0 || duration.Seconds > 0 ? (duration.Minutes > 0 && duration.Seconds > 0 ? ", " : " and ") : String.Empty);
        if (duration.Minutes > 0) 
            time.Append(duration.Minutes).Append(" minute").Append(duration.Minutes > 1 ? "s" : String.Empty)
                .Append(duration.Seconds > 0 ? " and " : String.Empty);
        if (duration.Seconds > 0) 
            time.Append(duration.Seconds).Append(" second").Append(duration.Seconds > 1 ? "s" : String.Empty);
```

... or if you really wanted to confuse people, go with the one-liner approach:

```
string message = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", duration.Hours <= 0 ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0} hour{1}", duration.Hours, duration.Hours > 1 ? "s" : String.Empty), duration.Hours > 0 && (duration.Minutes > 0 || duration.Seconds > 0) ? (duration.Seconds > 0 ? ", " : " and ") : String.Empty, duration.Minutes <= 0 ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0} minute{1}", duration.Minutes, duration.Minutes > 1 ? "s" : String.Empty), duration.Minutes > 0 && duration.Seconds > 0 ? " and " : String.Empty, duration.Seconds <= 0 ? String.Empty : String.Format("{0} second{1}", duration.Seconds, duration.Seconds > 1 ? "s" : String.Empty));
```

LOL, I have to admit scwagner's answer would be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an `int` number of minutes to the nearest quarter hour:

```
int quarters = (minutes + 7) / 15;
```

So, your method would probably look something like:

```
private static string Hours(Timespan ts)
{
    int quarters = (ts.Minutes + 7) / 15;
    if (ts.Hours == 0)
    {
       return quarters == 0 ? "" : String.Format("{0}/4 hour", quarters);
    }
    if (quarters == 0)
    {
       return String.Format("{0} hour", ts.Hours) + (ts.Hours != 1 ? "s" : "");
    }
    return String.Format("{0} {1}/4  hours", ts.Hours, quarters);
}
```